# one to many relationship in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mean stack to create a hybrid app.I'm using nosql to create DB in mongoose.My DB consists of two tables one is 'donors' and another one is 'bloodGroup'.
My 'bloodGroup' schema is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(mongoose) {
 var Schema = mongoose.Schema;  

  /* bloodGroup Schema */
  var bloodGroupSchema = new Schema({
   name: { type: String, required: true }
  });
}
```

My 'Donor'schema is as follows:

```
/* Donor Schema */
var DonorSchema = new Schema({
 Name: { type: String, required: true },
 DOB: { type: Date, required: true, trim: true },
 Sex: { type: String },
 BloodGroupID: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'BloodGroup', required: true },  
 ContactNo: { type: String, required: true },
 LocationId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Location', required:true },
 EmailId: { type: String, required: true },
 Password: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

When many donors refer to a single blood group then BloodGroup object Id error is reported.How to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please share error in question itself ?

Answer (score 1):

*You can refer this link for documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html*

> Saving Refs

```
    /* Donor Schema */
    var DonorSchema = new Schema({
     _id : {type: Number},
     Name: { type: String, required: true },
     DOB: { type: Date, required: true, trim: true },
     Sex: { type: String },
     BloodGroupID: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'BloodGroup', required: true },  
     ContactNo: { type: String, required: true },
     LocationId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Location', required:true },
     EmailId: { type: String, required: true },
     Password: { type: String, required: true }
    });


    /* bloodGroup Schema */
   var bloodGroupSchema = new Schema({
       _bid :{ type: Number, ref: 'Donor' },
       name: { type: String, required: true }
   });


    module.exports = mongoose.model('Donor', DonorSchema);
    module.exports = mongoose.model('Blood', bloodGroupSchema);


    var vidya = new Donor({ _id: 0, name: 'Vidya', sex: 'F' }); 
        vidya.save(function (err) {
          if (err) return handleError(err);

          var blood = new BloodGroup({
            name: 'B+',
            _bid: vidya._id    // assign the _id from the Donor
          });

          blood.save(function (err) {
            if (err) return handleError(err);
            // thats it!
          });
        });
```

Answer (score -6):

Mongo is not a Relational database, relation one to many does not exist in mongDB. The question is quite confusing, but following the title, you should either embed the donnors into the BloodGroup, or create an Id field unique to which you will refer and do two queries.

Comment: You are wrong. I suggest you to read http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87200945828/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1